# How to run a task after the page being killed in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, web-worker

First of all, it has two pages: `example.com/pageA` and `example.com/pageB`, it's not a SPA.

How to run a delay task after the page being killed by `history.back`?

I tried using `setTimeout` but failed to execute the task after `history.back`, because the `timer` will be clear in stack when page change.

```
var a = 1

function refresh() {
  // <p id="count"></p>
  count.innerText = a
}

function foo() {
  a += 1
  refresh()
}

// called in PageB
function goBackA() {
  setTimeout(foo, 1000)
  history.back()
}
```

In `PageA` the count still be 1 instead of 2.

Comment: `page being killed` please expand on how a page is "killed" in a browser? the phrase makes no sense

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, **after the page being killed by `history.back`**

Comment: Once you leave a page you kill all the javascript being run in it, the only way to have functions run once a page is killed is to have a single-page application where your page content change (something like react and react-router) where your app is still running as pages are changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reason, your goal to run some code after page being killed will never be supported by the browser, because it's dangerous when some code can run on a different page.

Once the page being reload/killed, all the unfinished tasks will be clear even if in a `SharedWorker`.

So, two ways to accomplish your logic:

1. change to SPA
2. give another page a hint like query